# Start/Stop all VMs under a specific subscription

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

I'm using Azure Powershell cmdlets to start/stop VMs.

```
Start-AzureVM [-ServiceName] <String> [-Name] <String> [ <CommonParameters>]

Stop-AzureVM [-ServiceName] <String> [-Name] <String> [[-StayProvisioned]] [[-Force]] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Is there a command to start/stop all VMs under a specific subscription rather than a single VM? If not, I'm looking for a script to run above code multiple times in parallel for each VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start-AzureVM and Stop-AzureVM now support wildcards, allowing you to parallel-start / parallel-stop any/all VMs within the same service name. Here, you can see this in action, where I just started a few VMs in a single service, in parallel:

[image: Calling Start-AzureVM]

[image: Parallel operation, seen in portal]

Now: If you wanted all VMs in the entire subscription, you could always enumerate all of your service namespaces, then start the VMs within. This is an example of that - tweak it as you see fit, for particular datacenter, etc.

Example of enumerating services:

```
Get-AzureService | Select ServiceName
```

Now to do something with that, instead of just listing the services:

```
Get-AzureService | Foreach-Object { Start-AzureVM -ServiceName $_.ServiceName -Name "*" }
```

Note: I didn't test that last one, as I didn't feel like starting all my VMs, but something like that should work for you as a bulk "start ever single VM in every single service in my subscription."

Comment: I had to replace -VM by -Name and add the -Force switch when using wildcard syntax.

Comment: Oops - that'll teach me to post code without testing. :) Edited param name.

Answer (score 0):

Very True- Start-AzureVM and Stop-AzureVM now support wildcards, allowing you to parallel-start / parallel-stop any/all VMs within the same service name.

As per the question start/stop all VMs under a specific subscription is not possible. However start/stop all VMs under a specific service name is possible.

Start-AzureVM -ServiceName "sa12345"
will start all azure vms under service name sa12345

Comment: Does this add anything new to the already given and accepted answer? I guess not...

Comment: I had faced the same challange. So, I just given my opinion :)